# Forbidden Error while setting up ACL in Menu

Tags: joomla-2.5, acl

Joomla ACL Set up

> Created a user Group (say:- channel)
>
> Edited its Permissions from Global Configuration (so that user belong to the group can login in front end)
>
> Mapped some users in that user group including super user (channel)
>
> Now created a new viewing access level (say:- vendor access)
>
> Went to a Menu Item say offer - changed viewing level to vendor access
>
> Now logged in front end of site - and menu offer does not show in front end of site

Even when logged in as super admin - this menu does not show in front end of site
When trying to access menu directly - it shows 403 forbidden error

What could be doing wrong. Testing using Joomla latest 2.5.27

Comment: To update, the issue is resolved by using ACL Manager component !!

Answer (score 1):

An ACL manager component helps, but I have an idea where you might have went wrong to begin with.

When creating a new access level, you may not have used "registered" as the parent user type to inherit settings from.  If you do that, you eliminate some of the hiccups that can occur when you are setting up specific ACL groups.